# How to delete data from Vector Search in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vector-search

I have created a vector search index on my collection in MongoDB, Now I want to delete some data from it let's say data is added with bookId=1, I tried deleting the data with

```
db.collection('inventory').deleteMany({"bookId":"1"});
```

But it's not deleted, Also Find() is also not returning the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use async await for the same.
Either use the statement in an async function

```
async function deleteData() {
     const res = await db.collection('inventory').deleteMany({"bookId":"1"});
     console.log(result)
}
```

or you can use callback.

```
db.collection('inventory').deleteMany({"bookId":"1"}).then((result) => {
     console.log(result);
})
```